# Можно ли реализовать при переходе на другую страницу подтверждающее окно?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, можно реализовать функционал когда переходишь на другую страницу, если в окне confirm согласиться - переходить, если нет - оставаться на страничке?
Моя попытка:
Даже не выводит лог в консоле

```
<body onunload="myTest">
```

```
    // object.addEventListener("unload", myTest);

    function myTest(e) {
        console.log('mytest')
        if (!confirm('Уйти?')) {
            e.preventDefault()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
  e.returnValue = dialogText;
  return dialogText;
};
```

```html
<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/">ru.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

```html
<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/">ru.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

Comment: Текст в сообщении поменять нельзя? Зачем эта переменная dialogText?

Comment: Действительно, нельзя. Примеры на [русском](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) и [английском](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) mdn разные.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<a href="http://site.ru">ссылка</a>
<script>
document.querySelector("a").onclick = () => {
    return confirm("Это Ваш изменённый текст");
}
</script>
```

или так:

```html
<a href="http://site.ru" onclick="return confirm('Вы действительно хотите покинуть сайт?')">ссылка</a>
```

Comment: В данном примере не будет уведомления когда переходишь на другую страницу в браузере, напримере при помощи кнопки вернуться назад.

Comment: Ещё вычитал, что перехватить нажатие на эту кнопку можно с помощью события [window.onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) но у меня что-то не работает.